# Fatal signal 11 in background thread only on 4.4.2

Tags: java, android, multithreading, mapfragment, background-thread

I have an activity that displays a screenshot of a map fragment, along with some other things. Everything shows up perfectly until a second or two later when the app crashes. This is only happening on Android phones using 4.4.2 kitkat, but not on tablets. After the first attempt to load this view, it will sometimes crash before even displaying anything when setContentView is called. Since it crashes at a different time each time I test, I assume something is happening on a background thread, and since it's a Fatal signal 11 I assume it's some sort of strange memory problem, but other than that I really have no clue what's going on.

Here's the activity:
    public class TransactionDetailActivity extends CommonActivity implements Animation.AnimationListener {

```
    private TransactionDetail _transaction = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.transaction_detail);
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        if (mapFragment.getMap() != null) { // can be null if google play services isn't installed
            mapFragment.getMap().getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(false);
        }

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String transactionReceiptNumber = intent.getStringExtra("transactionReceiptNumber");
        loadTransactionDetail(transactionReceiptNumber);

        ClipDialog.showDialog(this, getString(R.string.transaction_detail_loading));
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        if (_runAnimation) {
            final ImageView mapScreenshot = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.map_screenshot);

            MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
            if (mapFragment.getMap() != null) {
                mapFragment.getMap().snapshot(new GoogleMap.SnapshotReadyCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSnapshotReady(Bitmap snapshot) {
                        mapScreenshot.setImageBitmap(snapshot);

                        Bitmap screenshot = Rotate3dAnimation.takeScreenshot(TransactionDetailActivity.this);

                        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.screenshot);
                        imageView.setImageBitmap(screenshot);

                        findViewById(R.id.container).setVisibility(View.GONE);

                        disableActionBarAnimation();
                        getActionBar().hide();

                        imageView.startAnimation(new Rotate3dAnimation(false));
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        if (_runAnimation) {
            View imageView = findViewById(R.id.screenshot);

            if (imageView != null) {
                Rotate3dAnimation anim = new Rotate3dAnimation(true);
                anim.setAnimationListener(this);

                imageView.startAnimation(anim);
            }

            _runAnimation = false;
        }
    }    

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
        ImageView mapScreenshot = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.map_screenshot);
        mapScreenshot.setImageBitmap(null);

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.screenshot);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(null);

        findViewById(R.id.container).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        disableActionBarAnimation();
        getActionBar().show();
    }

    private void loadTransactionDetail(String receiptNumber) {
        ClipAPIClient.getInstance().getAPI().transactionDetail(ClipDataManager.getInstance().getCurrentUser().merchant.id, receiptNumber, new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void success(Object object, Response response) {
                _transaction = (TransactionDetail) object;
                configureViewForTransaction();
                ClipDialog.hideDialog();
            }

            @Override
            public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                ClipDialog.showDialogForDuration(TransactionDetailActivity.this, getString(R.string.transaction_detail_error));
                L.e(error, "Transaction detail error");
                AnalyticsClient.logError("TransactionDetail", error);
            }
        });
    }

    private void configureViewForTransaction() {
        findViewById(R.id.map_container).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        findViewById(R.id.scroll_view).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        LatLng coordinate = new LatLng(new Double(_transaction.latitude), new Double(_transaction.longitude));
        MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        if (mapFragment.getMap() != null) { // can be null if google play services isn't installed
            mapFragment.getMap().addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(coordinate));
            mapFragment.getMap().moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(coordinate, 14));
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the xml involving the map fragment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000"
    >
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="#f8f8f8"
        >
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/map_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
            android:visibility="gone"
            >
            <fragment
                android:id="@+id/map"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
                />
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/map_screenshot"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                />
        </FrameLayout>
```

And here's the logcat:

```
I/ActivityManager( 3638): Timeline: Activity_launch_request id:com.payclip.clip time:64253930
I/ActivityManager(  478): START u0 {cmp=com.payclip.clip/.activities.TransactionDetailActivity (has extras)} from pid 3638
W/AudioTrack(  478): AUDIO_OUTPUT_FLAG_FAST denied by client due to mismatching sample rate (48000 vs 44100)
I/Google Maps Android API( 3638): Google Play services client version: 3225100
I/Google Maps Android API( 3638): Google Play services package version: 4452036
I/fpp     ( 3638): Making Creator dynamically
I/Google Maps Android API( 3638): Google Play services client version: 4452000
F/libc    ( 3638): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=1), thread 3694 (DataRequestDisp)
D/Retrofit( 3638): ---> HTTP GET https://devapitest02.payclip.com/payments/history/detail?merchant_id=3fb182ea-58cb-4d7f-a1b2-6c6088beab8c&receipt_no=NHPiZdY
D/Retrofit( 3638): Cookie: X-Blitz-Auth=MWQyN2M4NDgtYzgwYy00NmIyLWJkN2ItMTRhYWNhZjMxZTUx|1401984427|c4fe537b618705f306119435e3557734cf07eea1
D/Retrofit( 3638): ---> END HTTP (0-byte body)
I/DEBUG   (  129): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
I/DEBUG   (  129): Build fingerprint: 'google/mysid/toro:4.2.2/JDQ39/573038:user/release-keys'
I/DEBUG   (  129): Revision: '9'
I/DEBUG   (  129): pid: 3638, tid: 3694, name: DataRequestDisp  >>> com.payclip.clip <<<
I/DEBUG   (  129): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 00000000
I/DEBUG   (  129):     r0 00000000  r1 00000000  r2 608d404d  r3 00000019
I/DEBUG   (  129):     r4 00000008  r5 608d404e  r6 00000000  r7 ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (  129):     r8 00000001  r9 40adff50  sl 00000019  fp 608d404d
I/DEBUG   (  129):     ip 5c153b34  sp 63b87910  lr 5c148099  pc 40acaeae  cpsr 600f0030
I/DEBUG   (  129):     d0  0000000000000000  d1  0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (  129):     d2  0000000000000000  d3  0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (  129):     d4  c0000c66506245fe  d5  0000000032000007
I/DEBUG   (  129):     d6  000b0000010001ff  d7  0023000201000304
I/DEBUG   (  129):     d8  0000000000000000  d9  0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (  129):     d10 0000000000000000  d11 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (  129):     d12 0000000000000000  d13 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (  129):     d14 0000000000000000  d15 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (  129):     d16 0000000000000000  d17 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (  129):     d18 3cf0ec89e8959053  d19 36d009d3948721ab
I/DEBUG   (  129):     d20 0000000000ffffff  d21 0000000000000005
I/DEBUG   (  129):     d22 0000000009000000  d23 bebbb7c504f41aab
I/DEBUG   (  129):     d24 3e7ad7f29abcaf48  d25 3ff0000000000000
I/DEBUG   (  129):     d26 0000000000000000  d27 0000000000000001
I/DEBUG   (  129):     d28 bf8dd78e85b24937  d29 3e2d38fc57f240cc
I/DEBUG   (  129):     d30 bfc67dae64a5e000  d31 3fc5528670f6093a
I/DEBUG   (  129):     scr 60000013
I/DEBUG   (  129): 
I/DEBUG   (  129): backtrace:
I/DEBUG   (  129):     #00  pc 00026eae  /system/lib/libssl.so (SSL_select_next_proto+49)
I/DEBUG   (  129):     #01  pc 00007095  /system/lib/libjavacrypto.so
I/DEBUG   (  129):     #02  pc 0002f223  /system/lib/libssl.so (ssl_parse_serverhello_tlsext+434)
I/DEBUG   (  129):     #03  pc 000180dd  /system/lib/libssl.so (ssl3_get_server_hello+1008)
I/DEBUG   (  129):     #04  pc 000174d5  /system/lib/libssl.so (ssl3_connect+564)
I/DEBUG   (  129):     #05  pc 00026471  /system/lib/libssl.so (SSL_connect+20)
I/DEBUG   (  129):     #06  pc 0001201d  /system/lib/libssl.so (ssl23_connect+2292)
I/DEBUG   (  129):     #07  pc 00027c27  /system/lib/libssl.so (SSL_do_handshake+50)
I/DEBUG   (  129):     #08  pc 0000aeaf  /system/lib/libjavacrypto.so
I/DEBUG   (  129):     #09  pc 0001ea50  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmPlatformInvoke+116)
I/DEBUG   (  129):     #10  pc 0004f667  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallJNIMethod(unsigned int const*, JValue*, Method const*, Thread*)+398)
I/DEBUG   (  129):     #11  pc 00027ee0  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   (  129):     #12  pc 0002f3d8  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmMterpStd(Thread*)+76)
I/DEBUG   (  129):     #13  pc 0002ca7c  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInterpret(Thread*, Method const*, JValue*)+184)
I/DEBUG   (  129):     #14  pc 00061ae3  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallMethodV(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, bool, JValue*, std::__va_list)+338)
I/DEBUG   (  129):     #15  pc 00061b07  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallMethod(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, JValue*, ...)+20)
I/DEBUG   (  129):     #16  pc 000567f3  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   (  129):     #17  pc 0000d248  /system/lib/libc.so (__thread_entry+72)
I/DEBUG   (  129):     #18  pc 0000d3e0  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_create+240)
I/DEBUG   (  129): 
I/DEBUG   (  129): stack:
I/DEBUG   (  129):          63b878d0  40243d77  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
I/DEBUG   (  129):          63b878d4  0d427cfb  
I/DEBUG   (  129):          63b878d8  00000002  
I/DEBUG   (  129):          63b878dc  5c147fd1  /system/lib/libjavacrypto.so
I/DEBUG   (  129):          63b878e0  00000002  
I/DEBUG   (  129):          63b878e4  5c147fd1  /system/lib/libjavacrypto.so
I/DEBUG   (  129):          63b878e8  00000003  
I/DEBUG   (  129):          63b878ec  40a9be64  /system/lib/libcrypto.so
I/DEBUG   (  129):          63b878f0  401fa1b8  
I/DEBUG   (  129):          63b878f4  40a9be64  /system/lib/libcrypto.so
I/DEBUG   (  129):          63b878f8  5ef837b8  
I/DEBUG   (  129):          63b878fc  401bcf37  /system/lib/libc.so (dlmalloc+4250)
I/DEBUG   (  129):          63b87900  00000003  
I/DEBUG   (  129):          63b87904  00020384  
I/DEBUG   (  129):          63b87908  401bbe9d  /system/lib/libc.so (dlmalloc)
I/DEBUG   (  129):          63b8790c  00000003  
I/DEBUG   (  129):     #00  63b87910  40a9be64  /system/lib/libcrypto.so
I/DEBUG   (  129):          63b87914  63b87990  
I/DEBUG   (  129):          63b87918  63b8798c  
I/DEBUG   (  129):          63b8791c  608d404d  
I/DEBUG   (  129):          63b87920  00000019  
I/DEBUG   (  129):          63b87924  608d404d  
I/DEBUG   (  129):          63b87928  578d1bc0  
I/DEBUG   (  129):          63b8792c  63b8798c  
I/DEBUG   (  129):          63b87930  63b87990  
I/DEBUG   (  129):          63b87934  5ef83598  
I/DEBUG   (  129):          63b87938  40adff50  /system/lib/libssl.so
I/DEBUG   (  129):          63b8793c  00000019  
I/DEBUG   (  129):          63b87940  608d4049  
I/DEBUG   (  129):          63b87944  5c148099  /system/lib/libjavacrypto.so
I/DEBUG   (  129):     #01  63b87948  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  129):          63b8794c  ffffffff  
I/DEBUG   (  129):          63b87950  608d4066  
I/DEBUG   (  129):          63b87954  63b879c8  
I/DEBUG   (  129):          63b87958  63b879c8  
I/DEBUG   (  129):          63b8795c  608d404d  
I/DEBUG   (  129):          63b87960  00003374  
I/DEBUG   (  129):          63b87964  40ad3225  /system/lib/libssl.so (ssl_parse_serverhello_tlsext+436)
I/DEBUG   (  129):     #02  63b87968  00000019  
I/DEBUG   (  129):          63b8796c  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  129):          63b87970  40adb4a5  /system/lib/libssl.so
I/DEBUG   (  129):          63b87974  00000001  
I/DEBUG   (  129):          63b87978  00000001  
I/DEBUG   (  129):          63b8797c  63b879cc  
I/DEBUG   (  129):          63b87980  608d4062  
I/DEBUG   (  129):          63b87984  608d4066  
I/DEBUG   (  129):          63b87988  5ef83598  
I/DEBUG   (  129):          63b8798c  5d907490  
I/DEBUG   (  129):          63b87990  40a99dc0  /system/lib/libcrypto.so
I/DEBUG   (  129):          63b87994  5ef83598  
I/DEBUG   (  129):          63b87998  0000005a  
I/DEBUG   (  129):          63b8799c  608d400c  
I/DEBUG   (  129):          63b879a0  5d9076a8  
I/DEBUG   (  129):          63b879a4  608d402f  
I/DEBUG   (  129):          ........  ........
I/DEBUG   (  129): 
I/DEBUG   (  129): memory near r2:
I/DEBUG   (  129):     608d402c c0000c66 32000007 00000000 010001ff  
I/DEBUG   (  129):     608d403c 000b0000 01000304 00230002 00743300  
I/DEBUG   (  129):     608d404c 70730819 332f7964 7306312e 2f796470  
I/DEBUG   (  129):     608d405c 74680833 312f7074 0000312e 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  129):     608d406c 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  129):     608d407c 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  129):     608d408c 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  129):     608d409c 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  129):     608d40ac 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  129):     608d40bc 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  129):     608d40cc 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  129):     608d40dc 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  129):     608d40ec 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  129):     608d40fc 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  129):     608d410c 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  129):     608d411c 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  129): 
I/DEBUG   (  129): memory near r5:
I/DEBUG   (  129):     608d402c c0000c66 32000007 00000000 010001ff  
I/DEBUG   (  129):     608d403c 000b0000 01000304 00230002 00743300  
I/DEBUG   (  129):     608d404c 70730819 332f7964 7306312e 2f796470  
I/DEBUG   (  129):     608d405c 74680833 312f7074 0000312e 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  129):     608d406c 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  129):     608d407c 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  129):     608d408c 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  129):     608d409c 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  129):     608d40ac 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  129):     608d40bc 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  129):     608d40cc 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  129):     608d40dc 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  129):     608d40ec 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  129):     608d40fc 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  129):     608d410c 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  129):     608d411c 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  129): 
I/DEBUG   (  129): memory near r9:
I/DEBUG   (  129):     40adff30 00000040 00000020 00000002 00000002  
I/DEBUG   (  129):     40adff40 00000105 0000c030 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  129):     40adff50 00000001 40ad6440 0300c007 00000080  
I/DEBUG   (  129):     40adff60 00000040 00000004 00000002 00000002  
I/DEBUG   (  129):     40adff70 00000041 0000c030 00000080 00000080  
I/DEBUG   (  129):     40adff80 00000001 40ad6454 0300c008 00000080  
I/DEBUG   (  129):     40adff90 00000040 00000002 00000002 00000002  
I/DEBUG   (  129):     40adffa0 00000181 0000c030 000000a8 000000a8  
I/DEBUG   (  129):     40adffb0 00000001 40ad646d 0300c009 00000080  
I/DEBUG   (  129):     40adffc0 00000040 00000040 00000002 00000002  
I/DEBUG   (  129):     40adffd0 00000181 0000c030 00000080 00000080  
I/DEBUG   (  129):     40adffe0 00000001 40ad6484 0300c00a 00000080  
I/DEBUG   (  129):     40adfff0 00000040 00000080 00000002 00000002  
I/DEBUG   (  129):     40ae0000 00000181 0000c030 00000100 00000100  
I/DEBUG   (  129):     40ae0010 00000001 40ad649b 0300c00b 00000020  
I/DEBUG   (  129):     40ae0020 00000010 00000020 00000002 00000002  
I/DEBUG   (  129): 
I/DEBUG   (  129): memory near fp:
I/DEBUG   (  129):     608d402c c0000c66 32000007 00000000 010001ff  
I/DEBUG   (  129):     608d403c 000b0000 01000304 00230002 00743300  
I/DEBUG   (  129):     608d404c 70730819 332f7964 7306312e 2f796470  
I/DEBUG   (  129):     608d405c 74680833 312f7074 0000312e 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  129):     608d406c 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  129):     608d407c 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  129):     608d408c 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  129):     608d409c 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  129):     608d40ac 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  129):     608d40bc 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  129):     608d40cc 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  129):     608d40dc 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  129):     608d40ec 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  129):     608d40fc 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  129):     608d410c 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  129):     608d411c 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  129): 
I/DEBUG   (  129): memory near ip:
I/DEBUG   (  129):     5c153b14 40a319e5 409f5a8d 40a2812d 40a27dd1  
I/DEBUG   (  129):     5c153b24 40a28b25 40a20e65 40a2c10d 401bf0cd  
I/DEBUG   (  129):     5c153b34 40acae7d 401ba8a8 401ba9ac 40a3f3d5  
I/DEBUG   (  129):     5c153b44 40aca6fd 40158927 40186559 401295b5  
I/DEBUG   (  129):     5c153b54 40a34491 40a2cded 40a2cc61 40a2cc01  
I/DEBUG   (  129):     5c153b64 40a2d169 40a2f1f9 401d178d 40a2f1d9  
I/DEBUG   (  129):     5c153b74 40a2f2bd 401b9cd1 401bf4a5 401bdfc5  
I/DEBUG   (  129):     5c153b84 401296f5 40acaef9 40acddb1 40a66cd5  
I/DEBUG   (  129):     5c153b94 409ff4b9 409ff5a1 40a66d1d 40a0271d  
I/DEBUG   (  129):     5c153ba4 409f8991 409fb1a1 40a66475 40a5a135  
I/DEBUG   (  129):     5c153bb4 40a01189 40a049b1 40a34dc1 40a04a55  
I/DEBUG   (  129):     5c153bc4 409f48b5 40a35405 40a25345 40a25695  
I/DEBUG   (  129):     5c153bd4 40a24ec5 40a250c9 40a254e1 40a24e4d  
I/DEBUG   (  129):     5c153be4 40a252dd 40a3f279 40a252e9 40a252e1  
I/DEBUG   (  129):     5c153bf4 40a251cd 40a36b09 40a36a0d 40a36e41  
I/DEBUG   (  129):     5c153c04 409f5a95 40a2578d 409f3951 409fea55  
I/DEBUG   (  129): 
I/DEBUG   (  129): memory near sp:
I/DEBUG   (  129):     63b878f0 401fa1b8 40a9be64 5ef837b8 401bcf37  
I/DEBUG   (  129):     63b87900 00000003 00020384 401bbe9d 00000003  
I/DEBUG   (  129):     63b87910 40a9be64 63b87990 63b8798c 608d404d  
I/DEBUG   (  129):     63b87920 00000019 608d404d 578d1bc0 63b8798c  
I/DEBUG   (  129):     63b87930 63b87990 5ef83598 40adff50 00000019  
I/DEBUG   (  129):     63b87940 608d4049 5c148099 00000000 ffffffff  
I/DEBUG   (  129):     63b87950 608d4066 63b879c8 63b879c8 608d404d  
I/DEBUG   (  129):     63b87960 00003374 40ad3225 00000019 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  129):     63b87970 40adb4a5 00000001 00000001 63b879cc  
I/DEBUG   (  129):     63b87980 608d4062 608d4066 5ef83598 5d907490  
I/DEBUG   (  129):     63b87990 40a99dc0 5ef83598 0000005a 608d400c  
I/DEBUG   (  129):     63b879a0 5d9076a8 608d402f 40adff50 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  129):     63b879b0 00001110 40abc0e1 63b879c8 63b879c4  
I/DEBUG   (  129):     63b879c0 5ef83598 00000001 5c1481f9 608d4032  
I/DEBUG   (  129):     63b879d0 5ef83598 00001120 5c1481f9 5c1481f9  
I/DEBUG   (  129):     63b879e0 00000000 00001120 00001000 40abb4d9  
I/DEBUG   (  129): 
I/DEBUG   (  129): code around pc:
I/DEBUG   (  129):     40acae8c d02c2b00 9f0f9701 21009102 4001f81b  
I/DEBUG   (  129):     40acae9c 0801f101 eb0bb1cf eb0b0001 90030508  
I/DEBUG   (  129):     40acaeac f8162000 f1009000 454c0a01 eb06d109  
I/DEBUG   (  129):     40acaebc 4628010a f7e54622 4601efcc 29002001  
I/DEBUG   (  129):     40acaecc eb0ad00a 42b80009 9a04d3eb 0104eb08  
I/DEBUG   (  129):     40acaedc 42912002 e000d3da 99029e03 1c729f01  
I/DEBUG   (  129):     40acaeec 7832603a b005700a 8ff0e8bd 3178f8d0  
I/DEBUG   (  129):     40acaefc 600b2b00 0100f04f f890bf18 6011117c  
I/DEBUG   (  129):     40acaf0c bf004770 11a4f8c0 21a8f8c0 bf004770  
I/DEBUG   (  129):     40acaf1c 11acf8c0 21b0f8c0 bf004770 4605b570  
I/DEBUG   (  129):     40acaf2c f8d54614 460e01bc f7e5b108 490cee42  
I/DEBUG   (  129):     40acaf3c 6296f240 44794809 46204401 ee2cf7e5  
I/DEBUG   (  129):     40acaf4c f8c52101 b13001bc 46224631 ee6cf7e5  
I/DEBUG   (  129):     40acaf5c f8c52100 460841c0 bf00bd70 ffffb4ae  
I/DEBUG   (  129):     40acaf6c 00013b02 4605b570 f8d54614 460e019c  
I/DEBUG   (  129):     40acaf7c f7e5b108 490cee1e 62aaf240 44794809  
I/DEBUG   (  129): 
I/DEBUG   (  129): code around lr:
I/DEBUG   (  129):     5c148078 46402300 f7fe2121 6a6aef9a b13c6aab  
I/DEBUG   (  129):     5c148088 000ce88d 46314638 9b084622 ef76f7fe  
I/DEBUG   (  129):     5c148098 e8bd2000 b53881fc b1884604 b1556a05  
I/DEBUG   (  129):     5c1480a8 ffccf7ff 68296803 47906d9a f7fe4628  
I/DEBUG   (  129):     5c1480b8 2000ef84 21006220 60e12001 bd386161  
I/DEBUG   (  129):     5c1480c8 b508bd38 6d5a6803 bd084790 6803b508  
I/DEBUG   (  129):     5c1480d8 47906dda b508bd08 6fda6803 bd084790  
I/DEBUG   (  129):     5c1480e8 6804b510 4084f8d4 bd1047a0 b513b40c  
I/DEBUG   (  129):     5c1480f8 6804ab04 2b04f853 40c8f8d4 47a09301  
I/DEBUG   (  129):     5c148108 401ce8bd 4770b002 b513b40c 6804ab04  
I/DEBUG   (  129):     5c148118 2b04f853 40f8f8d4 47a09301 401ce8bd  
I/DEBUG   (  129):     5c148128 4770b002 b513b40c 6804ab04 2b04f853  
I/DEBUG   (  129):     5c148138 41ccf8d4 47a09301 401ce8bd 4770b002  
I/DEBUG   (  129):     5c148148 6803b508 229cf8d3 bd084790 6803b508  
I/DEBUG   (  129):     5c148158 22acf8d3 bd084790 6804b510 42b0f8d4  
I/DEBUG   (  129):     5c148168 bd1047a0 6803b508 32b4f8d3 bd084798  
I/BootReceiver(  478): Copying /data/tombstones/tombstone_01 to DropBox (SYSTEM_TOMBSTONE)
W/ActivityManager(  478):   Force finishing activity com.payclip.clip/.activities.TransactionDetailActivity
W/ActivityManager(  478):   Force finishing activity com.payclip.clip/.activities.TransactionHistoryActivity
I/WindowState(  478): WIN DEATH: Window{41e898d0 u0 com.payclip.clip/com.payclip.clip.activities.AmountActivity}
I/WindowState(  478): WIN DEATH: Window{421551e8 u0 Panel:com.payclip.clip/com.payclip.clip.activities.TransactionHistoryActivity}
I/WindowState(  478): WIN DEATH: Window{421d9b40 u0 com.payclip.clip/com.payclip.clip.activities.TransactionDetailActivity}
I/WindowState(  478): WIN DEATH: Window{423ecf60 u0 com.payclip.clip/com.payclip.clip.activities.TransactionDetailActivity}
I/WindowState(  478): WIN DEATH: Window{4214a618 u0 com.payclip.clip/com.payclip.clip.activities.TransactionHistoryActivity}
I/ActivityManager(  478): Process com.payclip.clip (pid 3638) has died.
V/Zygote  ( 3701): Switching descriptor 32 to /dev/null
V/Zygote  ( 3701): Switching descriptor 9 to /dev/null
D/dalvikvm( 3701): Late-enabling CheckJNI
D/Zygote  (  132): Process 3638 terminated by signal (11)
```

On a 4.4.2 tablet, which doesn't crash, this is what shows after the view is all loaded:

```
D/dalvikvm(27019): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1137K, 14% free 12105K/14048K, paused 25ms, total 25ms
```

Comment: That's a null pointer dereference in the native SSL library.  It might be interesting to run it with adb logcate -v threadtime and see if you can figure out what the thread it is coming from is doing, then experiment and see if it has anything to do with the server being contacted or if it's purely local.  Interestingly https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=65633 seems to also be a null pointer in about the same call stack, even though that one is running a virtual x86.  If you can reduce your problem to a minimal reproducible case you might post it there.

Comment: wild guess - try updating 'google services' lib in your IDE and using the upgraded version of services in a variant of your 4.4.2 build and then test for the crash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it turns out that the crash was caused by an SSL error. I was using an older version of Retrofit that was causing bugs with not only google maps, but also with a Webview. The solution was to upgrade to the latest version of retrofit. Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: Which version you were using and updated to what version of retrofit?